Npm failed with return code: 3 and Node.js Tool Installer Task in Azure DevOps Pipeline Not Updating to Latest Version
I'm encountering an issue with the Node.js Tool Installer task in my Azure DevOps pipeline. Currently, the task is configured to use Node.js version 14.19.x. I am trying to update it to 18.19.x, but I'm having trouble with the update process.
Additional details:

Pipeline Type: UI-based (Classic)

Current Node.js Version in Task: 14.19.x

Desired Node.js Version: 18.19.x

Error Message: This is part of my build raw log:



Node.js version v14.19.3 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.14 or v18.10.
\> @my/app@0.0.0 pretestchromeheadless D:\a\1\s\my_app.Web
\> node git-version.js
Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 3

The nodejs tool installer uses 14.19.x. I clicked on the notification flag that indicated a new version of the task is available:

But how do I update it? I do not think I have necessary permissions to manually update either. Also noticed the PR automated by my colleagues uses 18.19.x version.
How can I ensure that the Node.js Tool Installer task is correctly updated to use 18.19.x to resolve the Npm failed with return code: 3 error?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Hi @Pearl, Good day, May I know if you have got a chance to check the answer by RUI to grant your user account in  yourAzure DevOps organization to edit this pipeline? Hope it helps resolve your query in this post. Thx.


The nodejs tool installer uses 14.19.x. I clicked on the notification flag that indicated a new version of the task is available

Do not confuse the version of the Node.js tool installer task with the Node version.

How can I ensure that the Node.js Tool Installer task is correctly updated to use 18.19.x

Version can be set in the Version Spec field:

Your screenshot seems to indicate you can't edit the task/pipeline, so this seems to be a permissions issue.
Your user is probably part of the Readers group, which don't have permissions to delete or edit build pipelines:

For more details regarding pipeline permissions please refer to Manage security in Azure Pipelines.
